# date function not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
$sql="select * from ctimings where date = DATE(NOW());";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    echo "fail";
  //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error("as"));


  }
```

I am trying to get all the rows from my table which have the date column filled with the current system date but somehow none of the date functions dont seem to work.It gives me an error in phpmyadmin that none of the rows has been selected where as infact there are two rows in my table where the date column has the value of sysdate.
Also 'date' is the correct column name of my table.

Comment: What is the data type of your `date` column?

Comment: it has the DATE datatype

Comment: What error do you get in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: it says no rows selected

Comment: Please run `SELECT NOW(),DATE(NOW());` and display it.

Answer (score 0):

If the date has the DATE datatype, try this

```
$sql="select * from ctimings where date = DATE(NOW());";
```

If the date has the `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype, try checking from midnight today

```
$sql="select * from ctimings where date >= DATE(NOW()) + (INTERVAL 0 SECOND);";
```

Comment: @eggyal I saw that. That's why I changed my answer and suggested doing backquotes around the date column.

Comment: @eggyal OK backquotes removed

Comment: that is what i have done as it has the DATE datatype but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because you are getting a type mismatch. Try converting both values to dates like so:

```
 $sql="select * from ctimings where DATE(date) = DATE(NOW());";
```

Comment: @user2474232: This suggests that, contrary to your earlier comment, the `date` column does not have the `DATE` datatype after all.

Comment: @user2474232 please up vote my answer. eggyal sometimes even the same types can be stored in slightly different format - by DATE()ing them both you are making sure they are the same type and format.